# objects as integral bounds

Tags: r

```
   integg <- function(t,a,b){  

   integrate(Vectorize(function(x){55}),lower=t-(a+b),upper=t-a)   
   }
```

I'm having what I think may be a simple problem.

I am integrating a constant over bounds that may vary.

If you were to think of this constant as a function, it only exists for values on the x-axis that are >= 0. I cant just set the lower bound == 0. Because there may be times when the lower bound is some value > 0.

It would probably be best to just write the constant as a function somehow.

A second problem I'm having is that I would like to make that value 55 as an object (x) which I can include as an argument to the function integg()

I am using Vectorize because that's the only way I know how to integrate constants.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing...  In any case, why can't you just set `lower=0`? (or set `b = t-a`) Or set `lower = ifelse(t - (a + b) < 0, 0, t - (a + b))` Maybe a more complete description of your entire problem will make this portion more clear.

Comment: does this make more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do exactly as you describe.  Add `x` as an argument to your `integg` function

```
integg <- function(t, a, b, intval) {
  u <- t - a
  l <- ifelse(u - b < 0, 0, u - b)
  integrate(Vectorize(function(foo, x) {55}), lower=l, upper=u, x=intval)
}
```

You could just write your own area calc if the function you're integrating is always constant:

```
integg2 <- function(t, a, b, intval) {
  u <- t - a 
  l <- ifelse(u - b < 0, 0, u - b)
  intval * (u - l)
}
```

Comment: this looks good, I was also having trouble running the constant. if it's because it's a function w/i a function. but I defined the constant as an object and used that as the 1st argument in the integral and that still didn't work.